# Can asp.net core (.net 5 ) web api controller redirect to web page

Tags: .net-5, webapi

since the .NET 5 web Api doesn't have a webpage or ui as such,
can we do a  redirect to another webpage (http://somedomain.com/)
Bit if i do the same in .net mvc it works fine .
IF we cannt do a redirect from api what is the alternative ?

Our requirement is to call web api , do some work inside that and redirect to web page

Below code for .NET 5 web Api doesn't work

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RedirectController : ControllerBase
{

[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetRedirect()
    {
        //Do some work
        return Redirect("http://somedomain.com/account?id=1234&code=NEW");
    }

}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        //Do some work
        return Redirect("http://somedomain.com/account?id=1234&code=NEW");
       
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Redirect in Web Api Controller (HTTP 302 Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386554/use-redirect-in-web-api-controller-http-302-found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663443/c-sharp-net-core-webapi-how-to-return-redirect-to-a-web-page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347625/how-to-redirect-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I Have a same issue like you, try any things but not work as I expect : return status code 302, now do you have any solution for this?